# CometD Failover Ability - VM Switch During Restart

Tags: virtual-machine, client-server, long-polling, cometd

I have a chat implementation working with CometD.

On front end I have a Client that has a clientId=123 and is talking to VirtualMachine-1

The longpolling connection between the VirtualMachine-1 and the Client is done through the clientId. When the connection is established during the handshake, VirtualMachine-1 registers the 123 clientId as it's own and accepts its data.

For some reason, if VM-1 is restarted or FAILS. The longpolling connection between Client and VM-1 is disconnected (since the VirtualMachine-1 is dead, the heartbeats would fail, thus it would become disconnected).

In which case, CometD loadBalancer will re-route the Client communication to a new VirtualMachine-2. However, since VirtualMachine-2 has different clientId it is not able to understand the "123" coming from the Client.

My question is - what is the cometD behavior in this case? How does it re-route the traffic from VM-1 to a new VM-2 to successfully go through handshaking process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a CometD client is redirected to the second server by the load balancer, the second server does not know about this client.

The client will send a `/meta/connect` message with `clientId=123`, and the second server will reply with a `402::unknown_session` and `advice: {reconnect: "handshake"}`.

When receiving the advice to re-handshake, the client will send a `/meta/handshake` message and will get a new `clientId=456` from the second server.

Upon handshake, a [well written](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_javascript_handshake) CometD application will subscribe (even for [dynamic subscriptions](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_javascript_subscribe_resubscribe)) to all needed channels, and eventually be restored to function as before, almost transparently.

Messages published to the client during the switch from one server to the other are completely lost: CometD does not implement any persistent feature.

However, persisting messages until the client acknowledged them is possible: CometD offers a number of listeners that are invoked by the CometD implementation, and through these listeners an application can persist messages (or other information) into their own choice of persistent (and possibly distributed) store: Redis, RDBMS, etc.

CometD handles reconnection transparently for you - it just takes a few messages between client and the new server.

You also want to read about CometD's in-memory [clustering features](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_java_oort).

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. 

There actually is an application built on top of CometD that I use. And I am not sure how to determine what the application does in case of this (restart/disconnect/fail) situation. 

Any idea how to determine what they do, without having access to one of their programmers? Note, the only thing I can do is turn off or restart one of the VM's while in use.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question in your comment. If you are on the client, and the server fails over to another server, the client application will be asked to re-handshake. What is the purpose of you determining what they do? Even if you know, what are you going to do?

Comment: I want to understand the application's behavior in the case of fail over. Since as of right now I do not have any mechanism in my framework that handles this type of failover. Also, I am storing the first client id in the db...this would require a db update?

Comment: I don't understand... You seemed to talk about a client-side application. But you're not storing the CometD `clientId` into a client-side RDBMS, right?

Comment: If I have an established longpolling connection, after each conversation, i do an update on DB so that I can keep track of the conversation history. WIth a failed VM, I would have to update the client id on all those records...

Comment: It's not optimal to use CometD's `clientId` to identify a client. Typically clients handshake and give some other unique identifier (email, username, etc.) that is better suited for storing e.g. chat conversations into a RDBMS. In this way, you are not forced to update your DB in case of a server failover.

Comment: Sure. That makes sense. We can get rid of the clientId (for the sake of discussion). How else could I possibly understand what the application is doing in case of VM failover? 

Basically, My application is talking to this Application that is built on top of CometD and I do not have contact with the owners of this said Application.

Comment: The application on top of CometD is sending us a meta/connect/ with advice reconnect=none. Do you believe this is the correct way of doing things in terms of failover, or should they send to us a reconnect=handshake advice?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @DonCode I'm not sure I understand who exactly is "us" and therefore the exact case. Feel free to open an issue to discuss your case at https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues - it's more appropriate than StackOverflow for a discussion.